# Magento sort media folder files by filename

Tags: sorting, magento, media

I want to sort media folder files by filename.I tried with

```
$collection = $this->getCollection($path)
        ->setCollectDirs(false)
        ->setCollectFiles(true)
        ->setCollectRecursively(false)
        ->setOrder('filename', Varien_Data_Collection::SORT_ORDER_ASC);
```

but it is not case sensitive.It sorts all upper case words first then lowercase. (Apple,Bat,apple)

Please help !!!

Answer (score 0):

You have to rewrite lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Filesystem.php
and change function

```
protected function _usort($a, $b)
    {
        foreach ($this->_orders as $key => $direction) {
            $result = $a[$key] > $b[$key] ? 1 : ($a[$key] < $b[$key] ? -1 : 0);
            return (self::SORT_ORDER_ASC === strtoupper($direction) ? $result : -$result);
            break;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:
- create a `test.php` file in magento root directory.
- change the name of media folder to `$sub_dir` variable.

```
<?php
        require_once 'app/Mage.php';
        Mage::app();

        $file = new Varien_Io_File();
        $sub_dir = "wysiwyg/new";
        $dir = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . $sub_dir . DS;
        $file->open(array('path' => $dir));
        $fileDetails = $file->ls();

        $allFiles = array();
        foreach ($fileDetails as $value) {
            $allFiles[] = $value['text'];
        }

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($allFiles);
        echo "</pre>";
    ?>
```